# Android Studio can't find installed Build Tool

Tags: android, android-studio

When I upgrade from version 2.1 to 2.2, I get this popup error:

> Error:Failed to find Build Tools revision 24.0.3
>   Install Build Tools 24.0.3 and sync project

But I have installed Build Tool 24.0.3, and SDK Manager can also see the version of build-tools has been installed. See the following figure：
[SDK Manager has been installed, but Andriod Studio can't find.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAwcm.png)

I tried to install in Andriod Studio, also installed complete. But finally showed no installation. See the following figure：
[It showed no installation after installed complete.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fs1TF.png)

My environment:

1.Windown 7(32bit)

2.Android Studio 2.2 Build #AI-145.3276617, built on September 15, 2016

3.JRE: 1.8.0_60-b27 x86

4.JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM by Oracle Corporation

What should I do? I sincerely look forward to your reply! Thanks.

Comment: Invalidate your cache from file menu.

Comment: @Dexter Yes, I tried to Invalidate and Restart the cache, but it doesn't work, still no find Build Toos.

Answer (score 0):

I'm so sorry, now it works. But I don't quite understand the reason.

After take Dexter's recommendations to invalidate the cache from file menu, and upgrade from version 2.2 to 2.2.1, and delete all files in the root directory of the build-tools directory, only to retain a number of similar to the 24.0.3 folder, then it works.

In order to verify, I put the backup file back to the build-tools directory before I run again, the problem has emerged. So I think, maybe 2.1 after the version of the build-tools directory is more stringent requirements.

I hope to provide a reference for everybody, I am sorry to bother you all, thank you all.